# How to pass parameters into MVC controllers?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, backend, web-development-server

What is the proper way to pass parameters into Asp.Net core MVC controllers. For example, I have a controller with the following signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Input>> PostInput(Input input, string OutputPath)
```

Note: Input is just some class I made. How do I call this function from my react application and pass in the parameters.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the `type of Input`  could you please share the details?

Comment: You cannot pass two parameter together either in [`[FromBody]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#frombody-attribute) neither in `[FromForm]` because its not allowed to pass more than one parameter within one action specially for `[FromBody]` context . So either you have to move the `OutputPath` into the class or pass the class property as method argument. You could get more details on the [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#frombody-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to pass `OutputPath` via query string,and pass `Input input` via form.Here is a demo:

Input:

```
public class Input {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async void PostInput(Input input, string OutputPath)
        {
            
        }
```

request:
[image]
result:
[image]

[image]

Also,you can pass both `OutputPath` and `Input input` via query string:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> What is the proper way to pass parameters into Asp.Net core MVC controllers. For example, I have a controller with the following signature?

You cannot pass two parameter together either in `[FromBody]` neither in `[FromForm]` because its not allowed to pass more than one parameter within one action specially for `[FromBody]` context . So either you have to move the OutputPath into the class or pass the class property as method argument. You could get more details on the [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#frombody-attribute).

Valid Signature Format: 1 With Method Argument fashion:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostInput(string input, string OutputPath)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

Output 1:

[image]

Valid Signature Format: 2 With Class Fashion:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostInput(Input input)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Model should be:

```
public class Input
    {
        public string InputPropertyName { get; set; }    
        public string OutputPath { get; set; }    
    }
```

Output 2:

[image]

Note: if you still have any further concern you could have a look our
[`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sources).